# Reading JSON object into java using JACKSON

Tags: java, json, jackson

I have a json object:

```
    {"Result":{"code":0,"description":"success"} ,
        "Tickets":[{
        "TicketDetails":[
                       {"Key":"tknum","Value":888},
                       {"Key":"tkDescription","Value":"test"},
                      ],
        "Requestor":[
                       {"Key":"name","Value":"abc"},
                       {"Key":"add","Value":"xyz"},
                      ]

      },
 {
     "TicketDetails":[
                       {"Key":"tknum","Value":333},
                       {"Key":"tkDescription","Value":"test1"},
                      ],
     "Requestor":[
                       {"Key":"name","Value":"abc2"},
                       {"Key":"add","Value":"xyz3"},
                      ]

      }

     ]
}
```

I dont want to use JSON Parser. Is it possible to read this JSON directly to a java pojo.
Example:

```
ObjectMapper mapper=new ObjectMapper();
TicketInfo info=mapper.readValue("above Json object",TicketInfo.class);
```

Comment: You state that you don't want to parse the JSON, and your question title states that you want to use Jackson -- but how do you think Jackson works? Hint: it ***parses*** JSON. This makes your question confusing.

Comment: HI, apologies for that. I do not want to use the Tree model of Jackson.

Comment: What *do* you want to use?

Comment: What exactly are you trying to achieve ?